# Getting values passed to new Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I am following the android programming tutorial here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

It details how to start a new activity and send some data to it.

I have these activities now: SplashActivity, LoginActivity, RegisterActivity, and MainActivity.

SplashActivity does a quick preference read to see if you are logged in. If you are, it passes a user ID to MainActivity thus:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_USERID, userID);
```

Where `userID` is a user ID number as `String`.

Both Login and Register Activity does its thing, which returns a valid user ID from network. They pass it to main activity using the same code snippet above.

This is defined in all three activity classes: `public final static String EXTRA_USERID= "com.example.myfirstapp.USERID";`.

Following the tutorial, I have this code in the `onCreate` method of MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String userID = intent.getStringExtra([LoginActivity].EXTRA_USERID);
```

Notice the square bracketed peice of code `[LoginActivity]`. I don't know what to put here. I don't know which activity starts the MainActivity. Putting `LoginActivity` seems to only work when the login activity starts the main activity. When people register or the user ID is read from preferences in SplashActivity, the return value is an empty string.

What is the method for determining which activity started MainActivity? Or is there a way to simply get the value passed to the activity without specifying from which Activity it is created?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you only need to put EXTRA_USERID as it is, 
its a Key for that value, so it does not matter which package it is in, or which activity started MainActivity, its just a key, and you dont have to use full qualified naming with keys also, ... its good to make sure no duplicate or some other same-key issue, but its a string represents a key for a value, so its basic key-value pair

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to [putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) is a string key you define that can be used to extract the value later on. The key should start with your app's package name.

It doesn't matter where you define the key as long as you pass the right key when you launch the intent - e.g.:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String EXTRA_USERID = "com.my.app.USERID";
}
```

If you launch MainActivity from LoginActivity or SplashActivity, you'll want to reference the same MainActivity.EXTRA_USERID string anywhere the intent is created. It might be easier to define a common function that takes the user ID and creates an intent with the right extra parameters.